# Saving DOM object image

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying to save a dom object into my c: drive folder... But how can I achieve that? I read many documents but fail to do it. Please help!

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($newurl);

foreach($html->find('img') as $img){

   $path = "../folder/";

   $file = file_get_html ($img->src);

   $file->save($path); //1st method, fails
   $img->save($path); //2nd alternative, fails too.

}
```

I know the last line is wrong. But I cannot figure it out..

Comment: Or at least, how can I convert $img to file?

Comment: Hi Mouse Tan, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need in your example is [file_get_contents()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php&ei=VvLcUeukNMWqrAfv34FY&usg=AFQjCNGNR3KFk9e-cIt8BQeQyO91aAxpfA&sig2=Lh3ZkkGtbt92Dur-OqDBCw).  I don't think `file_get_html()` is a function.

After that, you have to call [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) or its buddy `write()`.

Or, assuming you get the `src` address correct, why not use [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)?

```
copy ($img->src, $path)
```

---

> Or at least, how can I convert $img to file?

`$img` is a DOM node, not a file.  I'm pretty sure that if you save that, it will just save an `<img>` tag with its attributes, not an image.

---

*EDIT*

To reply to your comment:

The DOM is like an imaginary tree.  Each branch of the tree is a node.  These nodes aren't files, they're just child elements, like `<div>` or something.  So, when you call `save()` on a DOM document, it will just save a string of HTML that holds the node and its children.

A file is a whole different thing.  It's got to be opened, read, etc.  To do these operations, the user has to have permission to do that.  777 on *nix systems means a user can do anything to that file.

So, you're going to get the `src` (the address) of the image *file* from the DOM *node* and work with that *file*.  You don't need the node anymore, since all you want is the address.  Then, use the functions above to read, write, copy, whatever you want to do, to the *file* (not the node).

Basically, a node is just a string of HTML.  A file is actual data.  All DOM stuff just moves around the tree and looks at the branches.  That's called "parsing".

Comment: Hi Steve, I think copy will be a more appropriate choice because I am not dealing with file. Is DOM image object = files?

I have set the folder permission to 777. But it failed to open stream: Permission denied